# Lockfile exit status 127

Tags: r, lockfile

I've been trying to use lockfile in order to parallelize some of my processes. Unfortunately, I'm getting an exit status error of 127 whenever I try. Here's the part of my script that uses it (it's in a loop, written in R):

```
    lock.file <- paste("lockfile mutex.lock -1",sep="");
    print(system(lock.file))
    [... commands ...]
    system(paste("rm -f mutex.lock",sep=""))
```

Does anybody know what exit status 127 means or how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you google it first?  127 looks like it means illegal command/typo in bash

Comment: What OS are you running? Are you sure this is a valid command?

Comment: I'm running linux, and "lockfile mutex.lock -1" and "rm -f mutex.lock" are both valid commands. I'll also point out that when I'm running just one instance of this script (i.e., just one slave), the exit status is 0, which indicates that lockfile is working. It is only when I'm running parallel slave instances that all use lockfile that I get exit status 127. This is strange to me because the purpose of lockfile is to be able to implement it with multiple slaves--i.e., if it is multiple implementations that are causing it to fail, I'm not really sure what to do :/